# Problem with closing split windows in Vim

Tags: vim

I have two split windows in Vim (left one is my_file.txt, right one is terminal) with the help of `rightb vert term` in ".vimrc". For closing both windows I usually use `exit` in terminal and then `:q` for my_file.txt. But if I close windows in other order (first comes `:q` for file and then `exit` for terminal) process "Vim" is still alife and a window with my_file is opened. So I need to use `:q` one more time for closing my_file window. Can you suppose the reason?

Comment: just use `:qa` if you want to quit every buffer

Comment: thank you, `:qa!` works correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `:quit` a window while another window is still open, Vim remembers the *buffer* that was edited inside that window. You can see that via the `:ls` command. Now, when you `exit` from the terminal, this doesn't work like `:quit`, but rather that window is closed and Vim recalls the original buffer that was previously edited and quit. (You can also forcibly `:quit!` from the terminal even though the job is still running; Vim will then exit, as the last window was closed.)

If you're done with a buffer and you don't want it to "come back" (when another window becomes free and Vim searches for remembered buffers to display), **use `:bdelete` instead of `:quit`**.

Alternatively, if you know you're completely done with the Vim session and don't care about remembered buffers, just **use `:quitall`** (short `:qa`).